# Convert array into json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i have data which is an array like:

```
arr=["[[name,address,contact],[name1,address1,contact1],[name2,address2,contact2]]"]
```

How to change this array in json and get those value in a table in react.

Comment: So your array has one element, which is a string? Can it have more elements? What are `name`, `address`, `contact`? Do they represent string literals? Why would you want to convert this to JSON if you want to load values in a table? Maybe you misuse the term JSON (which is a text format)?

Comment: No it don't have more element. name,address, contact are the data coming from backend. i have to format them in table

Comment: You should adapt your backend so that it sends JSON compliant format to the client. That's how it's done. Think for a moment what would happen if your back-end data has a comma in it, or square brackets?

Answer (score 0):

Use json.parse

```js
arr=["[[name,address,contact],[name1,address1,contact1],[name2,address2,contact2]]"]
let datax = JSON.parse(arr[0].replace(/(\w+)/g, '"$1"'));
console.log(datax)
```